# how to Vary process times for agents , and call it during Delay block

Tags: anylogic

There is a process/delay block which should process agents with different timings, how do I perform this?

Initially I thought I could assign a parameter and change this for each agent, and the delay block would process agents according to time specified in Parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the delay depends on each agent, you need to create an agent type in which you add a parameter, let's say you call it `delayTime`. Then, you can access this parameter in the flow charts by calling

```
agent.delayTime;
```

You can write the above in the delay time field of the delay block.

Check:

https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.anylogic.help/html/processmodeling/agent-type.html?resultof=%22%63%75%73%74%6f%6d%22%20%22%61%67%65%6e%74%22%20%22%74%79%70%65%22%20

Comment: Thank you for response, But the delay block is unable to access agent.delayTime ffrom each type of agent

Comment: You need to provide more details so we can help. But my first guess is you didn't specify the agent type? Go to the source and make sure you choose the agent type as the one you created, the one that includes delayTime parameter.

Comment: Or simply in the delay block itself, select the agent type from the advanced tab

Comment: I did add parament and called it in Delay block, but  how do I configure the parameter, example product A 5 seconds, product B 10 seconds, product C 20 seconds of delay time     https://ibb.co/0thKshf
https://ibb.co/YBtwMLL

Comment: Again, you need to give more details for me to be able to help. What is determining the 5? 10? 20? etc. Is it a random function? Is it predetermined values in a database? Is it the result of previous parts of the model? Depending on what you want, things will be done differently.

Comment: So basically an "order" contains 10 units of 2 inch part, 5 units of 4 inch, I'm using SPLIT module after source to specify number of units, and using agent.delay time, here, (IT IS WORKING)........

Comment: I had a follow-up question, What would be a way to group these agents at the end,.....................An agent [name-order] is created, then it splits according to BOM's, and I assign different process timings on exit from Split block........what attribute can I assign here, to combine them at the end ?

Comment: Use the batch element. This is a useful article that may give you ideas https://noorjax.com/2019/07/02/dynamic-batches/

Comment: Thank you for sharing the article Emile!, really appreciate your help and guidance.